# Removing an idle socket

Tags: c#, sockets

In C# Asynch Socket Server  - I need to identify idle connections and remove them. How do I do that?  My client has a unique ID that I am setting in the DataHoldingUserToken  - the same client may drop the previous connections and create a new one. At that time I want to reach the socket that was serving the previous connection and dispose that socket and return it to the pool. How do I achieve that?

My code is here

```
    class DataHoldingUserToken
{
    internal Mediator theMediator;
    internal DataHolder theDataHolder;
   // internal dataProcessorAtrack AtrackProcessorHere;

    internal Int32 socketHandleNumber;

    internal readonly Int32 bufferOffsetReceive;
    internal readonly Int32 permanentReceiveMessageOffset;
    internal readonly Int32 bufferOffsetSend;

    public bool needToSendbackKP;
    public bool needToSendBackACK;
    public bool sendBackSameSignal;



    public int flagUnitType = -1;
    public Int64 unitID = -1;
    public Int32 seqIDINT = -1;
    public byte[] ACKToSend;

    private Int32 idOfThisObject; //for testing only   
    private object lockerForTokenList = new object();

    internal Int32 lengthOfCurrentIncomingMessage;

    //receiveMessageOffset is used to mark the byte position where the message
    //begins in the receive buffer. This value can sometimes be out of
    //bounds for the data stream just received. But, if it is out of bounds, the 
    //code will not access it.
    internal Int32 receiveMessageOffset;        
    internal Byte[] byteArrayForPrefix;        
    internal readonly Int32 receivePrefixLength;
    internal Int32 receivedPrefixBytesDoneCount = 0;
    internal Int32 receivedMessageBytesDoneCount = 0;
    //This variable will be needed to calculate the value of the
    //receiveMessageOffset variable in one situation. Notice that the
    //name is similar but the usage is different from the variable
    //receiveSendToken.receivePrefixBytesDone.
    internal Int32 recPrefixBytesDoneThisOp = 0;

    internal Int32 sendBytesRemainingCount;
    internal readonly Int32 sendPrefixLength;
    internal Byte[] dataToSend;
    internal Int32 bytesSentAlreadyCount;

    //The session ID correlates with all the data sent in a connected session.
    //It is different from the transmission ID in the DataHolder, which relates
    //to one TCP message. A connected session could have many messages, if you
    //set up your app to allow it.
    private Int32 sessionId;                

    public DataHoldingUserToken(SocketAsyncEventArgs e, Int32 rOffset, Int32 sOffset, Int32 receivePrefixLength, Int32 sendPrefixLength, Int32 identifier)
    {
        this.idOfThisObject = identifier;

        //Create a Mediator that has a reference to the SAEA object.
        this.theMediator = new Mediator(e);
        this.bufferOffsetReceive = rOffset;
        this.bufferOffsetSend = sOffset;
        this.receivePrefixLength = receivePrefixLength;
        this.sendPrefixLength = sendPrefixLength;
        this.receiveMessageOffset = rOffset + receivePrefixLength;
        this.permanentReceiveMessageOffset = this.receiveMessageOffset;
        this.needToSendbackKP = false;
        this.needToSendBackACK = false;
      //  this.AtrackProcessorHere = new dataProcessorAtrack();

    }

    //Let's use an ID for this object during testing, just so we can see what
    //is happening better if we want to.
    public Int32 TokenId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idOfThisObject;
        }
    }

    internal void CreateNewDataHolder()
    {
        theDataHolder = new DataHolder();
    }

    //Used to create sessionId variable in DataHoldingUserToken.
    //Called in ProcessAccept().
    internal void CreateSessionId()
    {
        sessionId = Interlocked.Increment(ref Program.mainSessionId);                        
    }


    public Int32 SessionId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sessionId;
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        this.receivedPrefixBytesDoneCount = 0;
        this.receivedMessageBytesDoneCount = 0;
        this.recPrefixBytesDoneThisOp = 0;
        this.receiveMessageOffset = this.permanentReceiveMessageOffset;
       // this.needToSendBackACK = false;
       // this.needToSendbackKP = false;

    }

}
```

}

//AddTokenToList is firing inside the message handler for the first incoming data on  a new connection

```
bool incomingTcpMessageIsReady =  messageHandler.HandleMessage(receiveSendEventArgs, receiveSendToken, remainingBytesToProcess);

if (incomingTcpMessageIsReady == true)
{
   ...
   AddTokenToList(receiveSendToken);
}




private void AddTokenToList(DataHoldingUserToken theUserToken)
        {
            lock (this.lockerForList)
            {
                DataHoldingUserToken uTokenHere;
                for (int countT = 0; countT < Program.listOfTokens.Count; countT++)
                {
                    uTokenHere = (DataHoldingUserToken) Program.listOfTokens[countT];
                    if (uTokenHere.unitID == theUserToken.unitID)
                    {
                        //remove the previous socket

                    }
                    else {
                        Program.listOfTokens.Add(theUserToken);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is connection oriented. When your peer closes the connection gracefully, meaning the client does not crash or pull out the plug, he will do a close on the socket. The server detects this close by a receive on his end of the socket of 0 bytes. Getting this means it is time to close your end of the socket as well.

When using TCP and if no message exchange is going on, there is no way to detect that the TCP connection is broken. The only way to detect that the connection is gone is by either using keep alive, or by sending a simple message to the client from your server at every time interval, effectively implementing keep alive yourself. If the client does not respond after a few retransmits, you can close your connection.

Comment: thanks for that angle.  There is a keep alive coming in from client every 5 minutes, so I was already thinking to setup a timer for 6 minutes - and if there is no incoming  activity in those 6 minutes then I can close the socket?  If yes please tell me where to initiate the timer - at the accept socket, at the send/receive socket creation or at the dataholdingusertoken  -  Where do initiate the timer ?  and how do i eventually close the socket after the timer.elapsed event is fired.

Comment: The client has a keep alive going every 5 mins. I am using a Timer to run every 6 mins and remove the sockets if the last time of activity is more then 5 mins.  At each received signal am storing the time of last activity in the user token.  This is all working well. But on detecting more than 6 mins how do I close the socket from the list? There is a function CloseClientSocket - but it is not working as expected !!

Comment: It sounds like the right api function, but what behavior do you see ?